# U-NET predicts transposed masks

Tags: python, image-processing

I trained a **U-NET** to segment brain masks.
My net is surprisingly accurate but with one problem which has me pulling my hair.

The output of the net is transposed. 
If we input an image of (512,672,50),
It gives me an output of (50,672,512).
Transposing them does not help, as they do not overlap then.

As I have a 3d image, I am passing slices to the net and appending the outputs to a new one.
It maybe a beginner's problem, but i cant seem to debug it.

The code:-

```
i=1
final_ar=[]
for l in range(slices):
    x=np.array(x_test[l])
    x=np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    predict = model.predict(x, verbose=1)
    predict = (predict > 0.5).astype(np.uint8)
    temp_ar = np.squeeze(predict[0])
    temp_ar = crop_center(temp_ar,height,width)
    final_ar.append(temp_ar)
    print(i)
    i = i+1
final_ar = np.array(final_ar).T #to see overlapping
final_mask = nib.Nifti1Image(final_ar, affine=np.eye(4))
nib.save(final_mask, '/home/vaibhav/mask_nw/mask.nii.gz'
```

Thanks in advance!
Vb

Comment: Could you also share your network architecture? From your question, I could just figure out that (50,672,512) your channels are shifting. Usually when you build the model you provide the channels first e.g `model.build(input_shape=(None, 3, 572, 572))`. If you could share your model architecture, it might be helpful to answer you better.

Comment: The problem got resolved.I used np.dstack instead. worked wonders.